# Usage de "à moi" au lieu de "moi" dans le langage populaire

Tags: pronoms, prépositions, oral, registre-familier, évolution

Dans le milieu populaire et dans le sud de la France en particulier, le pronom tonique ***moi*** est parfois précédé de la préposition ***à*** dans des cas qui ne semblent pas être justifiés.

Voici un exemple entendu dans une télé-réalité :

> *Pourquoi tu ne me regardes pas à moi !?*

au lieu de :

> *Pourquoi tu ne me regardes pas moi !?*

Est-ce incorrect ? D'où cela vient-il ?

Comment: La téléréalité n'est pas vraiment une référence en langue française... Il y a souvent des mélanges d'expressions et des fautes évidentes de grammaire... Certains s'en amusent en en faisant des zapping, tellement les fautes flagrantes sont courantes...

Comment: @random Pour moi, la téléréalité est justement une référence du langage populaire !

Comment: Je ne pense pas que les fautes de grammaire fassent parti du langage populaire. Dans les téléréalités, c'est un manque d'éducation qui pousse à faire des fautes, comme un enfant apprenant à parler. Le fait de mélanger les expression doit être un effet de bord, où ils veulent "paraître intelligent" en utilisant des expressions, mais ne les ayant jamais utilisé, ils se trompent... Du coup il faut bien différencier les "fautes", et le langage populaire. Quel est votre niveau de français ? Quelle est votre langue maternelle ? Dans quel but voulez vous apprendre le langage populaire ?

Comment: @Random Les frontières entre langage soutenu, courant, populaire et fautif sont floues et évoluent dans le temps. Les fautes que l'on peut entendre dans la téléréalité ou ailleurs font partie du terreau d'où le langage se construit. Certaines expressions correctes ne sont que des expressions fautives qui ont réussi.

Comment: Même la version "corrigée" me semble confuse et enfantine sinon incorrecte. Quel age ont les enfants de cette émission ? Possible confusion entre parler populaire et parler enfantin ?

Comment: Is the “moi” in the 2nd version (w/out “à”) being used in apposition with & to emphasize the “me”? (“Pourquoi tu lui parles, **elle** mais tu ne me parles pas, **moi**”)? It’s probably not the case for I’d expect a comma if it were, but if it is, I see it as different from the1st version (w/“à”), which I see as a not-particularly-emphatic (perhaps redundant) repetition of the pronoun in its *tonique* form w/a preposition for clarification (granted, “me” & “moi” don’t need clarifying, but clarifying “lui” (the neutral indirect pronoun) with “à Corrine” or "[à] elle” can serve a valid purpose.

Comment: Voir https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-01121653/document pour une analyse détaillée du phénomène, en français.

Comment: La routourne va tourner.

Comment: @RomainVALERI je ne vois pas de connotation enfantine dans les 2 phrases. Dans la version corrigée, j'imagine le squetch "manu" des inconnus, on l'un d'entre eux dit « je te parle pas à toi qu'il me dit » (où ici, l'usage de "à" est correct). Concernant la version entendu, j'imagine entendre cette phrase lors d'une dispute, avec un ton agressif, dans un combat de regards entre deux jeunes qui veulent s'intimider...

Comment: @Random pour répondre à ta question, ma langue maternelle est le français, j'ai eu 16 à l'écrit du bac et je suis cadre. Cela n'empêche nullement de s'intéresser à l'évolution de la langue, au langage populaire, aux spécificités régionales et à l'origine des fautes récurrentes. "Le pédant tient plus à nous instruire de ce qu'il sait que de ce que nous ignorons"

Comment: @clemtoy Ah ! Dans ce cas, je comprends mieux la démarche, merci :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Un phénomène similaire existe en Espagnol et dans bien d'autres langues romanes (appelé "marquage différentiel de l'objet" dans la littérature technique). Les objets directs humains (parfois animés en général) et définis sont marqués avec la préposition *a*/*à* (en Roumain *pe*) de manière plus en moins obligatoire selon les langues.

En Français, le phénomène est stéréotypé au variétés du Midi, où il semble en effet être plus fréquent. Mais il n'est pas inconnu ailleurs et est relevé sporadiquement dans les autres dialectes.

La cause profonde du phénomène, outre le désir des locuteurs de marquer différemment les êtres humains, plus importants dans le discours, semble découler de l'utilisation générale des objets directs et indirects dans les langues romanes: Les objets directs sont généralement des objets inanimés et qui subissent l'action (J'ouvre la porte), alors que les les objets indirects sont l'élément qui ressent ou fait l'expérience du verbe, sont souvent animés et peuvent être ce qui est le plus important de la phrase (Ça lui semblait étrange, à Corinne, ton histoire). La préposition *à* est donc une façon attrayante de marquer un objet direct placé plus défini et plus animé que la norme.

Et bien sur, il n'existe rien de plus défini, de plus thématique et de plus animé qu'un participant à la conversation: en d'autres termes, les pronoms *toi* et *moi*

Comment: Je ne sais pas pour pierre qui roule, mais eau qui dort fait sourdre la lumière sur ce charmant phénomène. Merci bien !

Comment: Super réponse ! Merci !

Comment: Par contre, cette réponse ne répond pas à la question "correct ou incorrect ?" même si elle éclaire sur la psychologie, voir la philosophie, de l'expression.

Comment: @MakorDal: c'est incorrect en français, pour les prescriptivistes ("évidemment", dirais-je, d'où la question. Dans mon expérience, même ceux qui l'emploient ont conscience que ça n'est pas très réglo comme tournure). Pour les autres, eh bien, c'est utilisé courament. Comme [dit jlliagre](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22078/usage-de-%C3%A0-moi-au-lieu-de-moi-dans-le-langage-populaire#comment42887_22078), certaines expressions correctes ne sont que des formes fautives qui ont réussi.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks utilisé couramment ??? ou ??? 40 ans en France, jamais entendu une seule fois cette faute.

Comment: Voir https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-01121653/document - section 3, p8, "nous avons recueilli des jugements de locuteurs de différentes régions sur différentes constructions de MDO: des phrases du type « tu l’as vu à lui ? », « on m’empêche à moi de faire ça », « je le déteste à lui ». Les jugements récoltés se classent en trois catégories: rejet catégorique, faible rejet, acceptation limitée. La grande majorité des réponses récoltées va dans la première catégorie : la construction est tellement rare qu’une bonne partie de la population francophone ne la reconnaît même pas."

Comment: @RomainVALERI: La question dit "Dans le milieu populaire et dans le sud de la France en particulier", et la réponse "… est stéréotypé au variétés du Midi, où il semble être plus fréquent - mais il n'est pas inconnu ailleurs et est relevé sporadiquement dans les autres dialectes". Ça me semble clair. Je t'accorde que c'est plutôt "extrêmement rare" que "courant", je me suis laissé emporter, mais tout de même, c'est employé.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Ah, j'avais mis de côté puis oublié la référence au sud de la France, j'avoue. Et ce n'était que de l'étonnement, je n'ai pas la prétention d'avoir tout entendu, je crois tout-à-fait à son emploi.

Comment: "D'où que tu me parles mal ?!". "C'est qu'est-ce que je dis !". "J'ai rien à voir dedans tout ça !". Autant d'expressions fautives qui vont réussir ? Bref, pourquoi vouloir atténuer ou nuancer le fait que c'est simplement faux ? Malgré qu'on fait comme qu'on veut au final.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps : Parce que - d'après moi - ce sont les locuteurs qui font la langue, pas le grammairien. http://xkcd.com/1576/ Parce qu'à moi qui parle espagnol, ça me sonne naturel [sic], *et à toi, ça ne te fait rien ?* Merci pour les autres fautes semblables (surtout les deux premières qui sonnent raisonnablement motivées à mes oreilles), et si tu veux faire des Q/R sur "d'où celà vient-il ?", ça m'intéresse.